# Replacing numbers in string

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, hex

The java math expression evaluator library I'm using requires hexadecimal numbers to be prefixed with a *0x*. The expression is passed as a string.

`String expr = "0xAE6+0x22";`

But while entering input I'd like to enter the numbers without the *0x* and then later prefix them. So I came up with an idea to extract the numbers using regex in the string, prefix *0x* and replace it.

```
String expr = "AE6+22";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0123456789ABCDEF]{1,}").matcher(expr);
        while (m.find()) 
            expr = expr.replace(m.group(), "0x" + m.group());
```

I later found out that this won't work because if the expression is say `45+4`, it becomes `0x0x45+0x4`. How do I prevent it from replacing the repeated numbers repeatedly?

Comment: Another approach: You could use `String#replaceAll()` with regex, regex could include `\b`[boundary] and operator. That would be easiest solution I could think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `replaceAll()` can do the job:

```
String expr = "AE6+22";
String regex = "([\\dA-F]+)"; // use "([\\da-fA-F]+)" to also support lowercase
String replaced = expr.replaceAll(regex, "0x$1");
System.out.println(replaced); // prints 0xAE6+0x22
```

Comment: Maybe `[\\da-fA-F]+` to deals with lower/upper case :)

Comment: Why have you used $1?

Comment: @ArjunU: It is a reference to the match of the capturing group number 1.

Answer (score 0):

My idea would be to use the operations performed such as +-/* etc as delimiters, where you append the 0x at the beginning of the expression and then after each delimiter where there are no parentheses' append the 0x, maybe a little clarification on the complexity might help someone better answer your question but i tried,, good luck!